# Matlab/Simulink Help building standalone exe from slx model that uses TCP/IP Receive Block from Instrument Control Toolbox

Tags: matlab, deployment, tcp, simulink, tcpclient

**High level question up front:**

Should I be using the TCP/IP Receive block from the Instrument Control Toolbox when building a standalone app from a Simulink model to communicate over ‘localhost’ (127.0.0.1) with another app built in C#/Unity or are there other alternatives I should consider? I only need my Simulink app to act as the TCP client and receive data only.

**Details:**

I’ve run into a confusing issue when trying to build a standalone app from a Simulink model that uses the TCP/IP Receive block from the Instrument Control Toolbox. Documentation for this block is linked [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpipreceive.html).

I have successfully built a standalone executable using the “mcc” command and I can run the executable without issue on my (first) PC which has a full Matlab R2023a licensed install plus Matlab runtime installed. Now, the issue comes when I try to run the executable on another (second) PC that has the correct Matlab runtime version R2023a (9.14) but does not have matlab installed. I have been able to run standalone executables on the second PC (that don’t have the TCP/IP Receive block) with the same setup for a few months now so I’m confident the issue is with trying to run a standalone executable containing the TCP/IP Receive block.

On the second PC, I get the error when trying to run the executable as shown in the attached image. I tried to capture the error with a try/catch ME statement and print the ME text and got the text shown in the second attached image.

[Error image 1 showing simulink:tools:rapidAccelExeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D7Eh.jpg)

[Error image 2 showing ME stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkv2e.jpg)

I inspected the C/C++ Code Generation documentation for the TCP/IP Receive block which states the following:

C/C++ Code Generation
Generate C and C++ code using Simulink® Coder™.
This block generates platform-specific code for the host machine's platform only (Windows®, macOS, Linux®). Set the Device vendor and Device type in Model Settings > Hardware Implementation. You must also select Support long long under Device details. You can only use a single conversion specifier for the ASCII format string parameter.

I didn’t know how to properly set the Device vendor and Device type but did try selecting “Support long long” but that didn’t fix the issue.

I’m also wondering if the second PC had a full matlab install if the executable would work? But why wouldn’t it work with just Matlab Runtime?

Lastly, I was trying to implement in Simulink a Matlab function block that calls tcpclient but was running into an error that “The current BuildConfig has not been set”.
———-

TL;DR
Tried to make standalone executable from a simulink model with the matlab command “mcc” and got something that works on a PC with both matlab and matlab runtime installed. On a second PC with just matlab runtime installed and not matlab, I get the error “Simulink:tools:rapidAccelExeError” when trying to run the exe.

**More Context:**

I am required by my employer to produce a standalone executable that acts as a TCP/IP client that receives data packets from a TCP/IP server sent as a uint8 vector from an external app built in C#/Unity. Both my simulink app executable and the C#/Unity app need to both run at the same time on a windows PC where they communicate over address 127.0.0.1 or localhost. The combined software package needs to be distributed to multiple customers around the globe. The C#/Unity app runs fine when users just drag and drop that package into the target windows PC I assume because it includes all required packages/libraries.

For more context we are designing a flight simulator where the aero/flight physics equations are done in simulink and we already have it setup to communicate with the C#/Unity app (which handles visualization of an aircraft) over UDP connection in a way where it works as a standalone app. The feature we are trying to add is to handle user triggered “events” over TCP such as when the user starts a session, pauses, resumes, restarts, and exits a session. I think as a workaround we can handle events over udp but in the long term for our system to be distributed to many customers and have a reliable event system, we would prefer to use TCP driven events.

I had also looked into using a matlab function block that calls the ‘tcpclient’ function but got an error when trying to run my model in simulink that states “The current BuildConfig has not been set”. Any idea how to address that?